# Error: FIRESTORE (9.6.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jestjs, react-testing-library

I encounter the following error:

```js
Error: FIRESTORE (9.6.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state
```

while trying to test my React component:

```js
export default function ImageList() {

    const [imagesUrl, setImagesUrl] = useState([]);

    useEffect( () => {
        
        const unsubscribe = getImages(setImagesUrl);

        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    return (
        // JSX
    )
}
```

`getImages` is a function that subscribes to Firebase Firestore with `onSnapShot` function:

```js
import { collection, onSnapshot from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { database } from "./setup";


const getImages = ( handleResponse ) => {

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot( collection(database, "/images"), snapshot =>  {

        const _imagesUrl = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data();
            _imagesUrl.push(data.imageUrl);

        });
        handleResponse(_imagesUrl);
    } )

    return unsubscribe;
}

export default getImages;
```

Below is my test component:

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

import ImageList from "./ImageList";

test("list of images exist", async () => {
    render( <ImageList /> );

    const imgElement = await screen.findByRole("img");

    expect(imgElement).toBeInTheDocument();

})
```

I have followed [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70343196) to isolate my React component with Firebase logic so that I can test each of them separately with React Testing Library and Jest, but it does not seem to work in my case.

Do you know I can resolve this issue?