# Firestore error when trying to push or pull from database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am using react-native and expo go. When trying to addDoc or any other firestore method i get the following error

> ERROR  [2024-02-08T10:54:21.968Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): FIRESTORE (10.7.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

I know my firebase config is setup correclty as I have been able to use the auth to create user accounts and login.

This is the function thats causing the error

```
const database = getFirestore();
  const userRef = collection(database, "Users")

  const addUser = async () => {
    try {
      let user = { fName: firstName };


    console.log("Adding user:", user);
    await addDoc(userRef, user);
    console.log("User added successfully");
    } catch (e) {
      alert (e)
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Am i missing any imports?

```
import { firebaseApp, auth } from "../firebase";
import { getAuth,  initializeAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, getReactNativePersistence} from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, addDoc, collection} from "firebase/firestore";
```

I have tried updating my firestore to the latest versions and adding catch methods to break down whats happening but still cannot figure it out.

Comment: check if [cant-write-firestore-tests-because-of-firestore-9-6-1-internal-assertion-fai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327245/cant-write-firestore-tests-because-of-firestore-9-6-1-internal-assertion-fai) solves you problem

Comment: Did you check to see if your `firstName` variable has a value?